# Crack the code? Puzzle

Tags: mastermind

[image]

Crack the code .
Can you.
Then you will be genius.

Comment: What is the source of this puzzle? Or did you make it yourself?

Comment: So, I found the likely source to this edited pic. https://listquiz.blogspot.com/2020/03/find-code-and-unlock-it.html - EDIT: It actually looks like it's from a different source as the above copied pic has curved corners; maybe a mobile app? How do we handle these?

Answer (score 3):

The number is

> $6824$.

Explanation:

- > From the fourth clue, one of $3817$ is correct and well placed. It can't be $1$ (that would contradict the third clue) or $3$ or $7$ (that would contradict the second clue), so it must be **$8$ in the second place**.
- > From the second clue, two numbers are correct and well placed. We know $3$ and $7$ are not in the solution, so it must be **$6$ in the first place** and **$4$ in the last place**.
- > Now the third clue is valid with $6$ correct but wrongly placed.
- > Finally, in the first clue, $4$ is wrongly placed, and $3$ and $9$ are not part of the solution, so the last number must be **$2$ in the third place**.

Comment: Rand, you should be an experienced enough PSE member to know better than to answer questions that are obviously going to be put on hold for lack of attribution.

Comment: @Gareth I'm here to have fun solving puzzles. There's no harm in that: it's not plagiarism since the OP isn't claiming to have made it themselves, and indeed there's no proof they *didn't* make it themselves.

Comment: @DavyM Worth leaving that as a comment on the *question* - it might influence people to reopen-vote based on "benefit of the doubt" arguments.